# Using a temporary login

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I login to the SE network with my GMail Open ID, but when I came to SuperUser.com today on another computer that's not mine, I was asked to login through the owner's GMail account. Is there a way to temporarily login with my GMail OpenID and let them stay logged in under their GMail for GMail? Even if it's just temporary, but I don't think I can word this right

Comment: I would tend to doubt it, but there might be something involving GMails's multiple login.

Comment: @soandos But that would mean that I'd have to link my login to theirs :(

Comment: Rgiht, hence I don't think it is possible.

Comment: @soandos That sucks... Should I make a feature suggestion for it then on SE meta?

Comment: maybe use a secondary open ID instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was asked to login through the owner's GMail account. Is there a way to temporarily login with my GMail OpenID

Yes, logout of the existing GMail account, logout of Stack Exchange. Then login to Stack Exchange - since you're not logged in to Gmail, you can login to your Google Account and then login to Stack Exchange.

Another option is to make use of Private Browsing/Incognito/inPrivate modes of different browsers

Comment: Forgot about inprivate browsing... Good idea!

Comment: cheers, @Luke !

Answer (score 1):

I always carry around a USB drive with [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/). It may be worth looking into the portable versions of Firefox, Chrome, etc. if the computers are running Windows.